# GreenRobot EventBus subscribe based on API level

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm attempting to subscribe to an EventBus event. Due to the parent class not existing in API level 23 and below, I'm in a situation where I need to conditionally subscribe to said event.

I realize that, through the use of build variants, it is possible to get around this, but I'm curious if there's a more elegant solution. The `@RequiresApi` annotation doesn't seem to have any effect (maybe stacking annotations doesn't work the way I expect it to).

Some simplified sample code:

```java
class MyClass : OtherClass() {
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun onSomeEvent(someEvent: SomeEvent) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Assuming `OtherClass()` is only available in API level 24+, the app will hang on the splash screen on lower API levels right after Dalvik or the ART realizes that the generated `EventBusIndex` references a broken class.

Comment: `@RequiresApi` has no effect on runtime behavior -- it is there for Lint to be smarter about what it warns you about. Do you get this crash even if you do not call `register()` to register your subscriber?

Comment: @CommonsWare Even after commenting out any `register()`/`unregister()` calls it will still hang on the splash screen due to the EventBusIndex.

Comment: OK, if you disable the EventBusIndex annotation processor, and do not register this subscriber on the older device, does it work?

Comment: @CommonsWare Disabling the EventBus annotation processor (and thereby also having to disable adding the index to the default event bus) will, as expected, fix the issue.

Comment: There's nothing stopping EventBus' annotation processor from either paying attention to something like `@RequiresApi` or having their own similar annotation property. My guess is that would require a feature request and some work on their part.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, figures. Do you know of any way to get around this in the meantime without needing to create more build variants?

Comment: You could refactor your code such that your subscriber is not extending a class that may or may not exist (e.g., have `MyClass` hold something that is the subscriber, rather than being the subscriber itself). Or you could disable the annotation processor. Other than those two options and the build variant solution, I don't have any great ideas -- sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to tweak `MyClass` somewhat to move the subscription to another object:

```
class MyClass : OtherClass() {
    val subber = Subber()

    fun onSomeEventForRealz(someEvent: SomeEvent) {
        // do some stuff
    }

    inner class Subber {
        @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        fun onSomeEvent(someEvent: SomeEvent) = onSomeEventForRealz(someEvent)
    }
}
```

You would also need to adjust your `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` calls to pass in `subber` instead of the `MyClass` instance itself.